# XSLT 1.0. Выбрать и обработать только узлы с текстом

Tags: xml, html, xslt

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кому не трудно, каким образом можно "вырезать" из документа текстовые узлы (или узлы, содержащие непосредственно текст) и "обернуть" их в пару элементов, сохраняя атрибуты родителя?

То есть, к примеру, есть такой кусок документа:

```
<div id="ui_combo_bodies_all_4371"><div id="cmbBody_src_combo" class="dropdown-menu ui-cmb-body  ui-cmb-body-hidden">
    <h1 margin-left="15" id="header">Заголовок</h1>
    <div class=" ui-cmb-content-container" >
        <div class="ui-cmb-pre-content">
            <div class="ui-cmb-scrollable"><div id="ccat_tree" class="ui-tree">
               <ul>
                 <li class="lvl-1">Вопрос по работе подсистемы</li>
                 <li class="lvl-1">Вопрос по методологии</li>
                 <li class="lvl-1">Ошибка в работе подсистемы</li>
                 <li class="lvl-1">Ошибка в данных</li>
                 <li class="lvl-1">Не нашли данные?</li>
              </ul></div></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-helper"></div>
        </div>
    <p border="1">Доп. параграф</p>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

А нужно получить:

```
<block>
  <string margin-left="15" id="header">
    Заголовок
  </string>
</block>

<block>
  <string class="lvl-1">
    Вопрос по работе подсистемы
  </string>
</block>

<block>
  <string class="lvl-1">
    Вопрос по методологии
  </string>
</block>

<block>
  <string class="lvl-1">
    Ошибка в работе подсистемы
  </string class="lvl-1">
</block>

<block>
  <string class="lvl-1">
    Ошибка в данных
  </string>
</block>

<block>
  <string class="lvl-1">
    Не нашли данные?
  </string>
</block>

<block>
  <string border="1">
    Доп. параграф
  </string>
</block>
```

Не могу найти, как это реализовать. Простое

```
<xsl:template match="p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|h9|i|b|div|li">
    <block>
        <string>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </string>
    </block>  
</xsl:template>
```

или выбор через

```
<xsl:template match="*[text()]">
```

не помогают: получается простая замена вместо выбора текстовых узлов.

Был бы очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Я все никак не могу понять, куда именно нужно делать конвертацию... Из html мы вырезаем текст и формируем xml? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Expert,

это даже не html, а кусок xml (привёл только часть документа). Мне бы понять принцип хотя бы на таком маленьком документе. XML -> XML.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за внимание. Мне подсказали ответ на мой вопрос. Нужно просто использовать

```
<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(text()) != '']">
```